# Слово "рутиничал"

Tags: словообразование

Вдогонку ещё один схожий вопрос. Грамотно ли использовать слово "рутиничал" в значении "жил рутинно"? Такого я слова не встречал, но полагаю, оно вполне себе употребимо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, от "жил рутинно" глагол будет *рутиННичал*, "рутиничал" - это производил рутину (ср. *полд**н**ичать*, но *пусты**нн**ичать*).

По поводу же употребимости окказионализмов, я уже вам писал - Можно, но аккуратно, главное, чтобы вас понимали и неологизм был оправдан с точки зрения стиля и логики текста.

Comment: Благодарю. Значит с двумя "нн" употреблю. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что "жил рутинно" звучит плохо. Что сие должно означать? Будьте проще, не надо этих выпендр... пардон, пардон.

Comment: И "рутинничал" звучит плохо. В нормальной обыденной русской речи.

Answer (score 0):

"рутинничал" - очень хорошее слово... "жил рутинно" - тоже замечательно.

Жил рутинно. Сквозь эту рутину
Видел свет, хоть смеялись кретины...